# Find a function s.t. $f(0), f'(0)$ exists but $f''(0)$ doesn't

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find a function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)$ exists and $f'(0)$ exists, but $f''(0)$ does not exist.

I have no idea how to solve this problem, I've tried many times.

Comment: $f(x)=\tan(x)$, if $x$ is rational, else $f(x)=x$.

Comment: $f(x) = x^{2}\sin (1/x), f(0) = 0$ then $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ but $f''(0)$ does not exist because $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 10):

Take

$f(x)=x^2$ if $x \ge 0$ and $f(x)=-x^2$ if $x <0$.

Show that $f'(x)=2|x|$  for all $x$. Hence $f'$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)$ be any continious function with no derivative at $x=0$ - for example $g(x)=|x|\,\,\text{or}\,\, g(x)=\sqrt[3]x.$ Then you will be satisfied with the antiderivative of $g(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^{5/3}$.  Then $f'(x)={5\over3}x^{2/3}$ for all $x$, and $f''(x)={10\over9}x^{-1/3}$ for $x\not=0$.

Note, to *prove* that $f''(0)$ does not exist, we need to consider

$${f'(0+h)-f'(0)\over h}={{5\over3}(h^{2/3}-0^{2/3})\over h}={5\over3h^{1/3}}\to
\begin{cases}
+\infty\quad\text{as }h\to0^+\\
-\infty\quad\text{as }h\to0^-
\end{cases}$$